# Open Source DB for business intelligence reporting on big data?

Tags: hadoop, hive

We have a unique reporting need at our company. We are collecting a large amount of data which comes in a file every X mins. The files could be between 1 to 5MB in size containing upto a million rows. Data is similar to log data that's never updated and is pretty structured. Although we need the flexibility to support changes in the data model. We need to deliver some canned(static) reports and also some reports as part of an interactive dashboard.

For canned reports, data needs to be refreshed only once a day. So I am going to use Hive for this. By end of the day, the file size will be in several Gbs and that’s when it will be pushed into Hadoop so we won't run into the small file issues with hadoop. Since the reports are static, it will not matter much even if Hive takes a few seconds/mins to return the data.

But Hive will not be able to meet our interactive dashboard needs as these reports need to load within a few seconds. These reports will mostly be time series reports , time series data will be stored for up to a year. I wanted to know what other databases can be used for data warehousing/BI purposes ? We need a stable open source database that works well with Big data, allows fast writes & reads, has a decent query language to enable reporting with minimal coding. Since we are going to use Hadoop+Hive for the canned reports, it will be ideal if this database could work directly with Hadoop.

I have looked at Hbase – but am not sure if it will work well with small files coming in every X mins. Is Hbase the right choice? Any other suggestions of DB are also welcome.

Our reports are quite basic and we'd love to keep the solution very simple.
P.S. We do not want to use MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally what you are looking is MPP databases like Netezza, Greenplum etc.  All of them are commercial. In other words - i am not aware about open source solution. Closest is probably infobright - which has
columnar engine for MySQL 
There is not good analytic open source DB. I mean DB with descent parallel query capability + clustering. 
So I would suggest some intermediate solution where Hive/Hadoop is doing heavy lifting of aggregation(building cubes) and RDBMS is used to serve interactive queries.

Comment: Thanks David. How about Hbase? Documentation says it is pretty good for random reads. Mostly our interactive dashboard will be reading Raw data.

Comment: I would expect that Dashboards will require number of aggregations. And here HBase is not that good (although it will change with coprocessors version). If you sure you will always access data by Key, or by range of Keys - HBase design can be considered.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest Greenplum database. It is not open source, but it has a single node edition which could serve terabytes of data without any problems. It has a quite good data loading engine and a query execution engine - both are parallel. HP Vertica will also have a community edition

Both Greenplum and Vertica have interfaces to hadoop/hbase/hive.

If you are interested only in open source, try MonetDB. It is open source, but I have no experiences with it.

Comment: Actually greenplum database become open source